# Mac OS X - iTerm updates causing multiple binaries

Tags: macos, iterm2

My question is basically, how do I solve this:

[image: iTerm binaries]

Every time I update iTerm a new binary is created and since I use Alfred, my instinct is to just type a name and hit Enter, so I don't even know if I am always picking the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Is it installed to the Applications folder?
If yes, you should remove the others from your Downloads folder (automatically by an Apple Script, if you want).

Comment: Agreed.  You should open your Downloads folder and delete all but the most recent version.  Personally, I MOVE the apps into the /Applications folder to prevent clutter and "disk disarray"